# cmake generate error

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

ok, i'm building a project that compiles successfully with provided .cmd script and cmakelists.txt with visual studio 2010 but with 2010 it gives me following error:

> 1>ClCompile:
>
> 1> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01
>   for x64
>
> 1> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> 1>
>
> 1> cl /c /W3 /WX- /O2 /Ob2 /D _WINDOWS /D NDEBUG /D
>   "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:precise
>   /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTryCompileExec.dir\Release\"
>   /Fd"C:/alembic/out/i64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Release/cmTryCompileExec.pdb"   /Gd /TC /wd4267 /wd4800 /wd4018 /wd4244 /errorReport:prompt
>   "C:\alembic\out\i64\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"
>   _DEBUG /Zm1000
>
> 1>
>
> 1> testCCompiler.c
>
> 1> _DEBUG
>
> 1>c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '_DEBUG': No such
>   file   or directory
>
> 1> Generating Code...
>
> 1>
>
> 1>Build FAILED.

and here is command i would like to get help to change

```
setlocal
if /i "%1" == "db:" (

    set DB=_db
    set config=Debug
    set linkFolderName=Debug
    set boost_suffix=-sgd
    set cmake_flags=/MTd /D_DEBUG /EHsc /GR
    set zlib_suffix=d
    shift
) ELSE (
    set config=RelWithDebInfo
    set linkFolderName=Release
    set DB=
    set boost_suffix=-s
    set zlib_suffix=
    set cmake_flags=/MT /U _DEBUG /EHsc /GR
)
)
```

thanks,

and please let me know if i can provide more info

Comment: please provide the 'CMakeLists.txt' file.

Comment: here:`http://code.google.com/p/alembic/source/browse/CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Hmm, isn't that space in `/U _DEBUG` extraneous?

Comment: it passes if i remove space but now i'm getting   `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or
  directory` when the script tries to compile zlib here is the /zlibtrycompile.cpp/ : `http://code.google.com/p/alembic/source/browse/build/bootstrap/zlib_trycompile/zlib_trycompile.cpp`

Comment: ok, solved this last one, with `-#ifndef PLATFORM_WINDOWS
-#include <unistd.h>
+#ifdef PLATFORM_WINDOWS
+#  include <unistd111.h>`where `-` is removed and `+` added, moving on

Comment: Had a nearly identical problem (also compiling Alembic) -- removing the space fixed it (thanks @arrowdodger!). For the next person: It was in the `init_Alembic.cmd` file (`Luxology_flags`).